# How to do async reduce or flatReduce with rxjs

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, rxjs, observable, reduce

Hi I want to do a sequence of ajax requests, each depending on the result of its predecessor.

My idea was to reduce the list of urls like this:

```
var urls = ["http://example.org/foo","http://example.org/bar", "..." ]

Rx.Observable
 .from(urls)
 .reduce((response, url, idx, source)=>{

   return Rx.DOM.ajax({ 
     url: url+'?param='+ response.yxz, //append some results to the next request
     responseType: 'json'
    }).map(data=>data.response)

 },{yxz:0})
  .subscribe(...
```

But the accumulator for reduce expects a "real" value to be returned.

Is there any way to make such a *flatReduce* call?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need reduce, because you don't want to accumulate all results.

You should think recursively here:

```
function tail(list) {
  return list.splice(-1, 1)
}


function request(urls, param) {
  if (urls.length <= 0) return param;
  return Rx.DOM.ajax({
    url: urls[0] + '?param=' + param,
    responseType: 'json'
  })
    .map(data => data.response.xyz)
    .flatMap(response => request(tail(urls), response));
}


request(["http://example.org/foo", "http://example.org/bar", "..."], 0)
  .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Hi myhau, thank you for your suggestion, sure I guess this would work but I would kind of leave rxjs function programming with operators. I could try to make this as a custom operator maybe

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this and was wondering exactly the same thing. The solution i came up with was to use the `Array.reduce` method instead:

```
var urls = ["http://example.org/foo","http://example.org/bar", "..." ]

urls.reduce((observable, url) => {

    return observable.flatMap(
        (response) => {

            return Rx.DOM.ajax({ 
                url: url+'?param='+ response.yxz, //append some results to the next request
                responseType: 'json'
            })
            .map(data=>data.response);
        }

}, Observable.of({yxz:0}))
.subscribe(...
```